# Inserted Word Table not showing Borders

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I can insert a table but the tables borders are not visible. You can see the created document. In order to allow others to run this script I have to use late binding which I suspect may be the cause.

[image: Created Word Document]

My Code is here:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
   Dim objWord As Object
   Dim objDoc
   Dim objSelection
   
   Dim i As Long
   
   Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

   Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add

   objWord.Visible = True

   Set objSelection = objWord.Selection

   objSelection.TypeText ("Insert table after this text")
   
   Set myRange = objDoc.Content
   myRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
   objDoc.Tables.Add Range:=myRange, NumRows:=3, NumColumns:=4
   
   Set myTable = objDoc.Tables(1)
   With myTable.Borders
     .Enable = True
     .InsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
     .OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleDouble
     .InsideColor = wdColorBlack
     .OutsideColor = wdColorBlack
   End With
   

End Sub
```

Comment: This did work and showed the border on my end, though you have undeclared variables and a typo here: `.InsideColor = wdColordBlack`

Comment: @RicardoDiaz Thanks, I fixed the typo however I am still having an issue of created table but no visible borders. Can you elaborate on "this did work"

Comment: Sure, I ran the script fixing the typo and it did showed the borders. I'm using Excel and word 365 on windows 10 machine

Comment: @RicardoDiaz hmm. would you mind posting your fixed code because mine is still not working. I am using the same versions of excel and word as well as being on windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s your code revised and in my testing it works when I run it from Excel.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim objWord As Object
    Dim objDoc As Object
    Dim objSelection As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim myRange As Object
    Dim myTable As Object
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    objWord.Visible = True
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
    
    Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
    
    objSelection.TypeText ("Insert table after this text")
    
    Set myRange = objDoc.Content
    myRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    Set myTable = objDoc.Tables.Add(Range:=myRange, NumRows:=3, NumColumns:=4)
    
    With myTable.Borders
      .Enable = True
      .InsideLineStyle = 1
      .OutsideLineStyle = 7
      .InsideColor = 0
      .OutsideColor = 0
    End With
   
End Sub
```

The issue with with the table borders not displaying is when using late binding you have to use the numeric values for the setting.

I also made a few other adjustments, they have no impact on the problem you were having, but they are better practices. All objects are declared and I added a test to see if the Word application was already running. In some releases of the Office applications, multiple instances of the application could get loaded into memory when you execute a CreateObject and the application was already there.

Comment: Thanks for the code and solution. I should note I was able to get my original code to work when I added ```.OutsideLineWidth = wdLineWidth150pt``` to my .Border block. But your solution is more robust so I will go with it as the answer. Thanks again for the help